# Using GDB to go through OpenFOAM source codes

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, openfoam

I'm a newbie using OpenFOAM-6. I'm trying to read the source codes by GDB. However, I cannot understand why GDB cannot step into the constructor of some classes like `fvMesh`. Also GDB reports something like

```
(gdb) p mesh
$1 = <incomplete type>
```

I first compiled an application `rhoSimpleFoam` in Debug mode. Basically, I export the variable `WM_COMPILE_OPTION` from Opt to Debug, and then compile the application. I also tried compiling the whole bunch of OpenFOAM in the Debug mode. No effects on what I will describe below. The Debug mode of `rhoSimpleFoam` is 3.8MB while the Opt version is 889KB.

Then I use gdb to run `rhoSimpleFoam` by

```
gdb <ThePathToDebugMode>/rhoSimpleFoam
```

The `rhoSimpleFoam.C` is as follows,

```
#include "fvCFD.H"
#include "fluidThermo.H"
#include "turbulentFluidThermoModel.H"
#include "simpleControl.H"
#include "pressureControl.H"
#include "fvOptions.H"

// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    #include "postProcess.H"

    #include "setRootCaseLists.H"
    #include "createTime.H"
    #include "createMesh.H"
    #include "createControl.H"
    #include "createFields.H"
    #include "createFieldRefs.H"
    #include "initContinuityErrs.H"

    turbulence->validate();

    // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //

    Info<< "\nStarting time loop\n" << endl;

    while (simple.loop(runTime))
    {
        Info<< "Time = " << runTime.timeName() << nl << endl;

        // Pressure-velocity SIMPLE corrector
        #include "UEqn.H"
        #include "EEqn.H"

        if (simple.consistent())
        {
            #include "pcEqn.H"
        }
        else
        {
            #include "pEqn.H"
        }

        turbulence->correct();

        runTime.write();

        Info<< "ExecutionTime = " << runTime.elapsedCpuTime() << " s"
            << "  ClockTime = " << runTime.elapsedClockTime() << " s"
            << nl << endl;
    }

    Info<< "End\n" << endl;

    return 0;
```

What I want to know is how the `fvMesh` is initialized, which should be done in `#include "createMesh.H"`. The file `createMesh.H` is as follows,

```
Foam::Info
    << "Create mesh for time = "
    << runTime.timeName() << Foam::nl << Foam::endl;

Foam::fvMesh mesh
(
    Foam::IOobject
    (
        Foam::fvMesh::defaultRegion,
        runTime.timeName(),
        runTime,
        Foam::IOobject::MUST_READ
    )
);
```

I set a breakpoint at `Foam::fvMesh mesh` in GDB and run to there. However, GDB cannot step into the constructor of that `fvMesh`. Instead GDB steps into `runTime.timeName()`. After that, GDB gets out of that file `createMesh.H`. The corresponding constructor of that `fvMesh` is as follows,

```
Foam::fvMesh::fvMesh(const IOobject& io)
:
    polyMesh(io),
    surfaceInterpolation(*this),
    fvSchemes(static_cast<const objectRegistry&>(*this)),
    fvSolution(static_cast<const objectRegistry&>(*this)),
    data(static_cast<const objectRegistry&>(*this)),
    boundary_(*this, boundaryMesh()),
    lduPtr_(nullptr),
    curTimeIndex_(time().timeIndex()),
    VPtr_(nullptr),
    V0Ptr_(nullptr),
    V00Ptr_(nullptr),
    SfPtr_(nullptr),
    magSfPtr_(nullptr),
    CPtr_(nullptr),
    CfPtr_(nullptr),
    phiPtr_(nullptr)
{
    if (debug)
    {
        InfoInFunction << "Constructing fvMesh from IOobject" << endl;
    }

    // Check the existence of the cell volumes and read if present
    // and set the storage of V00
    if (fileHandler().isFile(time().timePath()/"V0"))
    {
        V0Ptr_ = new DimensionedField<scalar, volMesh>
        (
            IOobject
            (
                "V0",
                time().timeName(),
                *this,
                IOobject::MUST_READ,
                IOobject::NO_WRITE,
                false
            ),
            *this
        );

        V00();
    }

    // Check the existence of the mesh fluxes, read if present and set the
    // mesh to be moving
    if (fileHandler().isFile(time().timePath()/"meshPhi"))
    {
        phiPtr_ = new surfaceScalarField
        (
            IOobject
            (
                "meshPhi",
                time().timeName(),
                *this,
                IOobject::MUST_READ,
                IOobject::NO_WRITE,
                false
            ),
            *this
        );

        // The mesh is now considered moving so the old-time cell volumes
        // will be required for the time derivatives so if they haven't been
        // read initialise to the current cell volumes
        if (!V0Ptr_)
        {
            V0Ptr_ = new DimensionedField<scalar, volMesh>
            (
                IOobject
                (
                    "V0",
                    time().timeName(),
                    *this,
                    IOobject::NO_READ,
                    IOobject::NO_WRITE,
                    false
                ),
                V()
            );
        }

        moving(true);
    }
}
```

Another problem I cannot understand is as follows. GDB is still in the file `createMesh.H`. GDB knows nothing about some variables, just like the following output.

```
(gdb) p runTime
$1 = <incomplete type>
(gdb) p runTime.timeName()
Couldn't find method Foam::Time::timeName
```

In fact, I use `info sources` in GDB to show the loaded symbols. For references for `info sources`, check this [webpage](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_12.html). The symbols have already been loaded.

So it seems like GDB knows really a little about OpenFOAM. GDB cannot step into a function body in some OpenFOAM classes. GDB cannot find some methods in OpenFOAM either.

Anyone could help me understand what's going on? Thanks!

Jingchang